# Error: GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify and therefore DynamoDB. I believe I have a fairly simple schema setup, but coming from MySQL my brain is going a little screw!!

The basic setup (a football league) is,

```
[League]
   [Season]
     [Divisions]
        [Teams]
           [Club]
              [Ground]
[Club]
  [Teams]
     [TeamConnection] (I needed a connection schema as a team can belong to multiple divisions/seasons/leagues. I could not think of another way to connect this on the `Team` model)
        [League]
        [Season]
        [Division]
```

Schemas

```
    ....
    Other Schemas
    ...
type Club @model @key(name: "byClub", fields: ["leagueID", "name"])
    {
      id: ID!
      name: String!
      leagueID: ID!
      leagues: [League] @connection(fields: ["leagueID"])
      teams: [Team] @connection(keyName: "byTeams", fields: ["id"])
      grounds: [Ground] @connection(keyName: "byGround", fields: ["id"])
    }

enum TeamGender {
      Male
      Female
    }
    
type Team @model
      @key(name: "byTeamsClubId", fields: ["clubID"])
      @key(name: "byTeams", fields: ["clubID", "name"])
      {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        faId: ID!
        clubID: ID!
        club: Club @connection(fields: ["clubID"])
        teamDetails: [TeamConnection] @connection(keyName: "byTeamsConnection", fields: ["id"])
        gender: TeamGender!
      }

type TeamConnection @model @key(name: "byTeamsConnection", fields: ["teamID","seasonID", "leagueID", "divisionID"])
    
    {
      id: ID!
      teamID: ID!
      leagueID: ID!
      seasonID: ID!
      divisionID: ID!
      leagues: [League] @connection(fields: ["leagueID"])
      teams: [Team] @connection(fields: ["teamID"])
      seasons: [Season] @connection(fields: ["seasonID"])
      divisions: [Division] @connection(fields: ["divisionID"])
    }

type Ground @model @key(name: "byGround", fields: ["clubID", "name"])

    {
      id: ID!
      name: String!
      address1: String
      address2: String
      town: String
      postcode: String
      rating: Int
      type: String
      link: String
      clubID: ID!
      clubs: [Club] @connection(fields: ["clubID"])
    }
```

### Error

This query works with no error

```
//$leagueID: ''
export const LIST_CLUBS = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListClubs($leagueID: ID) {
    listClubs(filter: { leagueID: { eq: $leagueID } }) {
      items {
        name
        leagueID
      }
    }
  }
`
```

This is the auto generated query used. If I used the **below query**, then the error seen below will kick in. This does confuse me.

```
//filter: { leagueID: { eq: leagueID } },

    export const listClubs = /* GraphQL */ `
      query ListClubs(
        $filter: ModelClubFilterInput
        $limit: Int
        $nextToken: String
      ) {
        listClubs(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
          items {
            id
            name
            leagueID
            leagues {
              items {
                id
                name
                faId
                logo
                seasons {
                  items {
                    id
                    name
                    faId
                    yearStart
                    yearEnd
                    leagueID
                    createdAt
                    updatedAt
                  }
                  nextToken
                }
                division {
                  items {
                    id
                    name
                    faId
                    divisionSeasonFaId
                    leagueID
                    seasonID
                    ageInput
                    level
                    createdAt
                    updatedAt
                  }
                  nextToken
                }
                createdAt
                updatedAt
              }
              nextToken
            }
            teams {
              items {
                id
                name
                faId
                clubID
                club {
                  id
                  name
                  leagueID
                  leagues {
                    nextToken
                  }
                  teams {
                    nextToken
                  }
                  grounds {
                    nextToken
                  }
                  createdAt
                  updatedAt
                }
                teamDetails {
                  items {
                    id
                    teamID
                    leagueID
                    seasonID
                    divisionID
                    createdAt
                    updatedAt
                  }
                  nextToken
                }
                gender
                createdAt
                updatedAt
              }
              nextToken
            }
            grounds {
              items {
                id
                name
                address1
                address2
                town
                postcode
                rating
                type
                link
                clubID
                clubs {
                  items {
                    id
                    name
                    leagueID
                    createdAt
                    updatedAt
                  }
                  nextToken
                }
                createdAt
                updatedAt
              }
              nextToken
            }
            createdAt
            updatedAt
          }
          nextToken
        }
      }
    `;
```

//Console

```
Error: GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
GraphQL error: Query condition missed key schema element
    at new ApolloError (/var/www/co.uk/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:92:26)
```

Query working as mentioned above.
[image]

Errors returned from GraphIQL

[image]
However frustratingly, which I did not know. The data is actually returned, plus the errors at the end.

[image]

Comment: ... specific filter arguments (variables) ?

Comment: Thanks @xadm I have updated. I have also added a screenshot, though I do not think it will help much, it does show the filterInput

Comment: and screenshot of version with query variables ?

Comment: Interestingly, which I did not realise. The data is actually returned from the query, but also with the errors as seen in the screenshots. I did not realise this nor understand why either.

Comment: I saw now, in the errors via GraphIQL that grounds seems to be casusing an issue. I have added the schema for this to the question.

Comment: usually errors are related to nulled props ... some invalid records? missing data? narrow query content to find the reason

Comment: Good thinking on the working backwards!! I'll do that in the morning thank you p

Comment: You were correct, if I removed any references to `ground` it would not fail. As there were no ground records.
It is not possible to let graphQL not error if there are no records? LIke a `left outer join`?

Comment: not a graphql problem - empty is simply nulled ... take dynamo separately? - error is about using field for relation (usually some condition for query) not being key/indexing field ... if some relations are working ok then compare their defs ... some existing db entries can be wrong (relations)? check in some db console/tool (idk dynamo)

Comment: yep, you are not wrong in this actually. My `Club` has a connection to my `Ground`. But these are not required fields as they are just `grounds: [Ground] @connection(keyName: "byGround", fields: ["id"])`

Comment: I saw/checked this earlier ... you still have to dig into dynamo relations